# What is the difference between using extract-text-webpack-plugin and linking a merged CSS file in an HTML header?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, webpack

From what I understand extract-text-webpack-plugin bundles all css files imported in your React components into a single separate CSS file. The separate CSS file can then be referenced in your HTML header to prevent FOUC (Flash Of Unstyled Content). Using extract-text-webpack-plugin counteracts some of the benefits of importing your CSS in your React component js files such as hot-loading.

What is then the difference between using extract-text-webpack-plugin and replacing all stylesheet imports in your component files with a single link to a merged CSS file in your HTML template header?

Does it matter whether you use CSS modules or import your CSS?

UPDATE: Added example for clarification.

Scenario A:

1. component1.css (imported in component1.js)
2. component2.css (imported in component2.js)
3. bundled CSS file generated by extract-text-webpack-plugin (called in the HTML header)

Scenario B:

1. component1.css (not referenced in js files)
2. component2.css (not referenced in js files)
3. master CSS file merged using SASS, Laravel mix.style method etc. (called in the HTML header)

Why go with Scenario A and not B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question ariebear!

If you want to use css modules, then yes, there's definitely a benefit to importing the css files into your js files/react components. The main one is that you no longer have to concern yourself with scoping issues, or worry about writing the same class in 2 different areas. The cascade becomes localized to each component.

If you're not using css modules, then there isn't much benefit at all. Sure, you get hot reloading, but there are other solutions available for that.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The advantages to combining all your stylesheets into one is that the browser makes a separate request for each stylesheet. If you combine several into one, you will only make one request. 
Using this plugin, your styles will no longer be inlined into your JS bundle, which can improve performance as the CSS bundle will be loaded in parallel to the JS bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking a lot of different questions here, so here's my best shot.

You'd use extract-text-plugin in production. Hot reloading isn't necessary in production and you're right that it gets rid of FOUC. There are a few other advantages listed [straight from the source](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin) as well.

You can still import your `.css` into your components, if you wish to- or keep them separate. It does matter if you import or require your CSS, that has to do with if you're using es2015 or not.

Comment: I read the advantages/caveats table before attempting to use extract-text-webpack-plugin. A lot of them seem to address the difference between importing CSS into your React component js files and creating a separate stylesheet. I'm not confused about that. I'm confused about the difference between using extract-text-plugin and using an alternate utility to merge your CSS. I can simply remove all references to css files in my React components, use an alternate utility to merge my CSS files and reference the merged file in my HTML header. Why use extract-text-webpack-plugin?

Comment: I mean you're sort of answering your own question. You'd use extract-text-plugin in production because of those advantages. I personally don't know of another util that would stand up to the way extract-text handles it already. Is there one that you know of? Extract-text fits easily into any webpack config and is fast, and you can inject the output with html-webpack-plugin. Is there an alternate utility that's better?

Comment: Sorry, I should have given an example.

Scenario A:

1. component1.css (imported in component1.js), 2. component2.css (imported in component2.js) 3. bundled CSS file generated by extract-text-webpack-plugin (called in the HTML header)

Scenario B: 
1. component1.css (not referenced in js files) 2. component2.css (not referenced in js files) 3. merged master CSS file merged using SASS, Laravel mix.style method etc. (called in the HTML header) Why go with Scenario A and not B?

Comment: So, you can put both of those together. You can write Sass, have it compiled through webpack, and served through ExtractText. Example: You'd write Sass in development, have it hot reload, and then bundle and serve it through ExtractText for your production build. Is that not an option?

Comment: It is an option. However, we don't use SASS or LESS so we're questioning whether there is any benefit to using the extract text plugin apart from maintaining hot loading in dev. It would be far easier to use Laravel's mix.styles to simply concatenate our stylesheets. Am I missing any other potential benefits to using extract text plugin? As I understand it, it maintains context, but that seems to only be true if you use CSS modules.